# relatively positioned paragraph goes beyond the viewport

Tags: html, css

```css
.feature {
    position:relative;
    left:50%; 
}
```

```html
<p class="feature">This is super cool feature..</p>
```

The above code causes the following: text gets centered, but the scrollbar appears horizontally. This makes me think that the width of `feature` paragraph still stays the same and that's why it goes beyond the viewport.

If I change the position to `absolute`, it doesn't go beyond the viewport anymore.

Why does this happen ? If we say that `absolute` positioning means that it's not part of the flow anymore, this answer wouldn't be enough. It mightn't be part , but still, width is the same, so it should be going beyond the viewport too as it happens for relative.

Comment: The code you've shown does not reproduce the error you describe in JSFiddle. We need to see a [mcve] of your code in order to help. Do you really have a page where this is the only content and you are encountering this problem?

Comment: Actually it looks like JSFiddle for some reason just doesn't want to show scrollbars. Must be how they implement the sandbox. CodePen repros it just fine.

Comment: i've added the answer to your question, take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be resolved, if you add border to the ".feature" element. in the below you could see that when we set "position:absolute" to ".feature" tag, the width of it reduces to its content:

```css
.feature {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%; 
    border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>positions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   

   <p class="feature">This is super cool feature..</p>

    
</body>
</html>
```

but you may say that if we have a longer text inside the ".feature" tag, it also does not go beyond the viewport. like this:

```css
.feature {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%; 
    border: 3px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>positions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   
   <p class="feature">This is super cool feature.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, perspiciatis aliquam deleniti atque sunt labore modi aperiam accusantium et, tempore quibusdam, nemo dolores necessitatibus nobis rerum accusamus illum asperiores quam nesciunt tenetur velit ipsa vel mollitia at assumenda? Recusandae et, molestiae totam officiis labore ab temporibus fugit odit corporis cum.</p>

    
</body>
</html>
```

in response to that I think the tag with the "position:absolut" is limited to the boundaries of its nearest parent with non-static position. so if we add a ".parent" to the html file you could understand that the ".feature" tag is always limited to it. and if the ".parent" goes beyond the view the ".feature" also goes beyond the view.

```css
.feature {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%; 
    border: 3px solid #000;
}


.parent {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #f21;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>positions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   
   <div class="parent">
   <p class="feature">This is super cool feature.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dignissimos, perspiciatis aliquam deleniti atque sunt labore modi aperiam accusantium et, tempore quibusdam, nemo dolores necessitatibus nobis rerum accusamus illum asperiores quam nesciunt tenetur velit ipsa vel mollitia at assumenda? Recusandae et, molestiae totam officiis labore ab temporibus fugit odit corporis cum.</p>
   </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

“Absolute positioning” is just like relative positioning, but the offset is relative to the entire browser window instead of the original position of the element. Since there’s no longer any relationship with the static flow of the page, please look at [normal flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Normal_Flow)

Normally, block-level elements per default take up the full available width of their container element. However, when you set position: fixed or absolute the element isn't displayed in the same sense as with the rest of the elements.

according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements):

---

### A block-level element occupies the entire space of its parent element (container), thereby creating a "block."

As such, the meaning of the container for a `block`-level element makes alters when refering to absolute or fixed positioned elements. It makes more sense to rather call it the parent.

Since there is no container element to inherit its width, you're seeing it behave more like an inline-block-type element if you inspect it you will see my explanation coming into hand.

**EDIT:**
if you want to see how absolutely positioned element's width is calculated
Look at [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width)

Answer (score -1):

paragraph default is display:block and take 100% width. Change to position absolute or change width of this .feature
The parent of .feature has a set position in css?